# JUnit Jupiter 5.10.0, failed to discover tests

Tags: junit-jupiter

After upgrading `junit-jupiter-engine` from 5.9.3 to 5.10.0 I started to get the following error. I'm running a Spring-Boot 3 application (spring-boot-starter-parent version 3.1.2).

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  12.187 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-07-25T12:27:39Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error:  Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0:test (default-test) on project wa-search-api: 
Error:  
Error:  Please refer to /home/runner/work/wa-search/wa-search/wa-search-api/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
Error:  Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
Error: [ERROR] There was an error in the forked process
Error:  TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
Error:  org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
Error:  TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
Error:      at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:631)
Error:      at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:285)
```

And from running on IntelliJ, I get:

```
Internal Error occurred.
org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:160)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverSafely(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:132)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discover(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discover(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:78)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:110)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/jupiter/api/io/TempDirFactory
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.config.DefaultJupiterConfiguration.<clinit>(DefaultJupiterConfiguration.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.JupiterTestEngine.discover(JupiterTestEngine.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:152)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.jupiter.api.io.TempDirFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 16 more
```

Any idea?

Comment: have you got any resolution for this problem? I am also getting the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to work around this issue with a roughly similar setup.
My versions are:

- JDK17
- Spring Boot 3.1.5
- JUnit 5.10.1

In my case, I **did not** have a dependency on `spring-boot-starter-test`.
For testing, I only had a dependency on `junit-jupiter`.

Adding `spring-boot-starter-test` to the dependency set as suggested above did, however, not solve the problem for me.
After some digging, I found the following documentation from [JUnit concerning Spring Boot specifically](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-spring-boot):

> Spring Boot provides automatic support for managing the version of JUnit used in your project. In addition, the spring-boot-starter-test artifact automatically includes testing libraries such as JUnit Jupiter, AssertJ, Mockito, etc.

Based on that, I made a guess that "I perhaps do not need `junit-jupiter` at all, but replace it with `spring-boot-starter-test`?"
After replacing the `junit-jupiter` dependency for `spring-boot-starter-test`, my tests started working again.

So in conclusion, I am letting Spring Boot provide the JUnit version instead of setting it consciously.
I hope this suggestion helps others too!

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, for me it stopped when I added the dependency to `spring-boot-starter-tests` and removed the dependency to `junit-jupiter-engine`, but keeping the dependency to `junit-jupiter`.

My final `pom.xml` has the following dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for opening the question, but I want to add that, sadly, the suggestion to add `spring-boot-starter-test` does not solve the predicament for me.